# porque mi programa no crea el archivo txt? C++

Tags: c++, fstream

acabo de crear un codigo corto que lo unico que hace es crear un archivo txt, pero no hace lo que le pido y no se que estoy haciendo mal

codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

ofstream entrada;

int main()

{
    entrada.open("archivo.txt",ios::out);
    if(entrada.fail())
    {
        cout<<"error";
    }
    entrada.close();
}
```

Comment: [Funciona perfectamente](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mHpY2XvpkG2UGoyE).

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BDsIgEEX3nILgBhLtAdqmdxnptE5CgQA1GtOzI7Y1auIs37z/Z7T3J23AjjkfyGoz98hbcjEFhKljH6Zj6g2dv9Hw3yLXMTZHsiO3MGH0oJEX3jDm9ghHmwL0UBDZxCcgKxVjD8bL7LvKebRSQNAXuroq3ZI4lsfq2s1JNatJg3zLA5CRSq14q3mNLm7bCgzBBbFllp8b2riIcq@L95hwksJEUciS8xM "C++ (clang) – Try It Online"). Ahí esta tu código, con una linea al final (`system("ls");`), que enlista los archivos en la carpeta en la que esta. Como puedes ver ahí sale `archivo.txt`. Seguro de que estas buscando el archivo en la carpeta correcta?